# When the variables saved as NSUserDefaults get released?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsuserdefaults

Can i save more variables as NSUserDefaults?
When these variables get released?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the app from the device then only the data in the NSUserDefaults will be erased .

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is not a mechanism for extending the lifetime of objects. It may not retain them at all (specifically, it may copy them and retain the copy instead)! It may save them to disk at arbitrary and unknowable intervals, and release them then. It may release them in response to memory pressure, or it may not.

NSUserDefaults is, only, a mechanism for storing and retrieving preferences. It's extremely good at that. Don't use it for other things.